# Blue Prism - SAP TreeView Integration

Tags: treeview, sap-gui, blueprism

I'm creating an automation using Blue Prism for the SAP `BMBC` transaction.

When I "spy" the menu with the results Blue Prism looks like SAP TreeView, this way I can expand the batch field using Navigate - "Expand Item" and passing the batch through Item Text.

But after expanding the Lot I need to select the product, if I use the "Select Item" Blue Prism does not find it in the TreeView.

I put an attached image where the yellow-highlighted field is what I can expand, and the red field is where Blue Prism can not select.

[image: SAP TreeView with emphasis]

Comment: What spy mode did you use to spy the elements?

Comment: I'm using the SAP Mode....

Comment: How badly do you want to avoid using Global Send Keys? Because if you want to avid them at all costs, you may have to look at SAP VBScripts.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the blue prism universe ... I don't know how global keys work, so I would not know the impact. At the moment I'm behind any solution that solves the question of the click in the field ...

Answer (score 0):

SAP TreeViews can be a pain to automate if they contain multiple levels. As you have noticed for yourself, you can use the `Navigate` stage to successfully select or expand the tree nodes on the first level, not on the second or lower. The actions that you can still use, however, are functions for the `Read` stage. The `Get Selected Item Text` can be useful.

What you need to do is resort to `Global Send Keys`, which means simulating key presses in the application. This is not the most robust of solutions, but if used carefully it can work just fine.

The approach you should take is this:

1. Spy the TreeView both with SAP mode and Win32 separately
2. Expand and Select the folder you can (using `Navigate` on SAP element)
3. Press 'DOWN' in the application (make sure to also use `Activate Application` to ensure the keys are sent to a correct window). Also, note that you use the `Global Send Keys` on the main, application node.
4. Read the currently selected node text
5. Decide whether you want to continue with the selected node
6. Press 'ENTER'

You may also need to include some unconditional `Wait` stages (half a second is more than enough) to ensure you are not sending the keystrokes to SAP before the Tree is ready (the items are expanded).

Please see my solution below:

[image]

Hope it helps!